# GitLab CI: reuse the same image in two independent parallel jobs

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am currently building two `Latex` documents in parallel using the `aergus/latex` container as follows (a `Makefile` is available in the repository):

```
stages:
  - compile

.compile_pdf_template:
  stage: compile
  image: aergus/latex

presentation:
  extends: 
    - .compile_pdf_template
  script:
    - make presentation
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - presentation.pdf

report:
  extends: 
    - .compile_pdf_template
  script:
    - make report
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - report.pdf
```

This works as expected, but it pulls the image twice (it is the slowest step in this simple pipeline, since the documents have few pages/slides). Is there any way to share the image across the two jobs, effectively pulling it only once, while keeping the jobs running in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you actually want to use the same ephemeral *container* for the jobs (they're already using the same image in your example pipeline YAML).  I don't believe there's any way to do that since the docker runner executor does a lot of work to ensure any two jobs *don't* share the same container context (for all the security reasons to not use the local shell runner executor).

It also sounds like the underlying need is around improving pipeline performance--in which case, you could try the following:

1. #### try using GitLab's Dependency Proxy

The [Dependency Proxy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/dependency_proxy/) essentially caches the packages (images in this case) in the GitLab application.  Depending on your environment, this might be more network-local to your runners, so it could speed up the image pull step (YMMV).  In a pipeline, you'd just add the CI variable for the group's proxy prefix:

```yaml
.compile_pdf_template:
  stage: compile
  image: ${CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX}/aergus/latex
```

2. #### target a specific private runner with job tags to re-use locally cached images

By default, Docker images are cached locally on the host, so if the hashes are the same, the runner can just re-use the local image (it will create a new container from it though). [NOTE that this adds overhead of setting up and managing your own runner.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/tutorials/create_register_first_runner/) It's not terribly difficult, but it may be more work than is warranted if you don't already have your own runner(s).

Assuming you have a private runner with the tag "my_private_runner", you could add the `tags` keyword to your example as follows:

```yaml
.compile_pdf_template:
  stage: compile
  image: aergus/latex
  tags:
    - my_private_runner
```

3. #### ditch parallel execution and just run the two script steps in the same job

Breaking down jobs for parallel execution is done to speed up pipelines, but if the overhead of setting up the container for the new job is longer than your script steps themselves, then there's no point.  Given the example in the question, this is by far the simplest solution.  Just join your script steps into a single job:

```yaml
stages:
  - compile

compile-pdf:
  stage: compile
  image: aergus/latex
  script:
    - make presentation
    - make report
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - presentation.pdf
      - report.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

All the jobs are independent, to speed up your process you can use the Shell Executor https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/ to make it faster

With this executor you will be able to use local docker images.

The first job will download the image from the docker hub and the next ones will get from the local docker service.

But if you are using other executors or Gitlab Shared Runner, this is the normal behaviour

Comment: According to the [executor's compatibility chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/#compatibility-chart), the ```image``` parameter is not supported in the Shell Executor. Are you suggesting that I should manually pull the container with ```docker``` commands, and then save it and retrieve it from a folder local to the Runner? Any code example would be much appreciated.

Comment: yes, it is not supported. You have to use the docker commands. 1. Pull the image in the machine that is running the runner. 2. In the `script` section of your job, run the docker commands. `docker login -> pull -> any other commands` 3. The runner will use the docker image that you pulled previously

Comment: I finally tried what you suggested, but am getting ```docker: command not found``` when running ```docker pull aergus/latex```.

Comment: Using docker in a shell executor imply that you have docker install on the system that host the runner :)